# Why do you need to encode URLs?

Tags: url

Why do you need to encode urls?  Is there a good reason why you have to change every space in the GET data to `%20`?

Comment: One good reason is that in printed material it is better to use `%20` so that some bod  can type it in without trying to guess the number of spaces!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From [RFC 2936](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), section 2.4.3:

> The space character is excluded
>   because significant spaces may
>   disappear and insignificant spaces may
>   be introduced when URI are transcribed
>   or typeset or subjected to the
>   treatment of word- processing
>   programs.  Whitespace is also used to
>   delimit URI in many contexts.

Comment: cant get more precise than the RFC

Comment: In other words, "No, there's not an inherent technical reason but we know implementors and users are both sloppy."  It was probably the correct decision, mainly because users would have trouble keeping the right amount of space.

Comment: @Matthew - There is a inherent technical reason, see my answer

Comment: @Rippo: Your answer claims that they are "unsafe", but does not give any technical reason why.

Comment: @Matthew - In my experience unsafe means that there must be a technical reason...

Comment: One could argue that according to ASCII the space character might be a control character. To make things safe for transport, you should encode all control characters, including those that are on the borderline, namely ASCII hex 20 / dec 32 / SP / Space.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question so much as tackle the special case used as an example.  The reasoning behind encoding spaces doesn't hold true for any other character that needs to be encoded.

Comment: This should be a comment. User doesn't provide any personal input rather than just copy pasting what the RFC docs say

Answer (score 62):

Because some characters have special meanings.

For instance, in a query string, the ampersand (`&`) is used as a separator between key-value pairs.  If you were to put an ampersand into one of those values, it would look like the separator between the end of a value and the beginning of the next key.  So for special characters like this, we use percent encoding so that we can be sure that the data is unambiguously encoded.

Comment: But, let's say you can encode `&` as `%26`. Still you could have a value containing the string like `100%26=22`. It still would look like the separator between key-val pairs isn't it??

Comment: No, because `%` is one of the characters with special meanings, so that too must be encoded (as `%25`).  If you had the string value `%26` then that would appear in a URL as `%2526` because the `%` would be encoded.  To get the string value, you'd decode the `%25` as `%`, leaving you with the string `%26`.

Answer (score 18):

- originally older browsers could get confused by the spaces (not really an issue anymore).
- now, if someone copies the url to send as a link - the space can break the hyperlink - ie

Hey! Check out this derping cat playing a piano!

```
http://www.mysite.com/?video=funny cat plays piano.
```

See how the link breaks?

Now look at this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/?video=funny%20cat%20plays%20piano.
```

Answer (score 11):

Let's break down your question.
**Why do you need to encode URL?**
A URL is composed of only a limited number of characters and those are digits(0-9), letters(A-Z, a-z), and a few special characters("-", ".", "_", "~").
*So does it mean that we cannot use any other character?*
The answer to this question is "YES". But wait a minute, there is a hack and the hack is **URL Encoding** or **Perchantage Encoding**. So if you want to transmit any character which is not a member of the above mentioned (digits, letters, and special chars), then we need to encode them. And that is why we need to encode "space" as "%20".
OK? Is this enough for URL encoding? No this is not enough, there's a lot about URL encoding but here, I'm not gonna make it a pretty big, boring technical answer. But If you want to know more, then you can read it from here: https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/ (Credit goes to this writer)

Comment: best answer for a beginner to understand

Answer (score -2):

Well, you do so because every different browsers knows how the string that makes up the URL is encoded. converting the space to %20, etc makes that URL/URI portable. It could be latin-1 it could be unicode.  It needs normalized to something that is understood universally.  Take a look at rfc3986 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1

Comment: Changing the representation of bytes does not specify an encoding. At least not literally.