# Difference between ContentUris.withAppendedId and Uri.buildUpon().appendPath

Tags: java, android, uri

I am a bit amateur and doing my android online course. I found these 2 different code snippets to append to an URI

```
 public static Uri buildWeatherUri(long id) {
     return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
 }
```

Here I get a URI with **id** appended to **CONTENT_URI**

```
public static Uri buildWeatherLocation(String locationSetting) {
     return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(locationSetting).build();
 }
```

Here I get a URI with **locationSetting** appended to **CONTENT_URI**

I'm wondering whether both have the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we assume:

```
CONTENT_URI = content://com.example.myapp
```

then

```
buildWeatherUri(5) -> content://com.example.myapp/5

buildWeatherLocation("location") -> content://com.example.myapp/location
```

Now let's see `ContentUris'` [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/froyo/core/java/android/content/ContentUris.java):

```
public class  ContentUris {

     public static long  parseId(Uri contentUri) {
         String last = contentUri.getLastPathSegment();
         return last == null ? -1 : Long.parseLong(last);
     }

     public static Uri.Builder  appendId(Uri.Builder builder, long id) {
         return builder.appendEncodedPath(String.valueOf(id));
     }

    public static Uri withAppendedId(Uri contentUri, long id) {
        return appendId(contentUri.buildUpon(), id).build();
    }
}
```

the difference is in using these two methods:

`appendEncodedPath` vs `appendPath`

[Encoding and Decoding URI Components](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html)

> Each component of a URI permits a limited set of legal characters.
>   Other characters must first be encoded before they can be embedded in
>   a URI. To recover the original characters from a URI, they may be
>   decoded.

So:

[appendEncodedPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendEncodedPath%28java.lang.String%29)

> Appends the given segment to the path.

[appendPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendPath%28java.lang.String%29)

> Encodes the given segment and appends it to the path.

Answer (score 3):

**appendPath (String newSegment)** encodes the given path segment and appends it to the end of the Uri object.

**withAppendedId (Uri contentUri, long id)** simply appends the given Id to the end of the given Uri object without encoding it.

**Example**-

- Have a look at this URI `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22`
- Since it is meant to be a URL we have to create it using **appendPath (String newSegment)** and appendQueryParameter(String key, String value) methods as both of them first encodes the arguments being passed to them before appending them.

  `Uri.parse("http://samples.openweathermap.org").buildUpon()
        .appendPath("data")
        .appendPath("2.5")
        .appendPath("weather")
        .appendQueryParameter("q", "London")
        .appendQueryParameter("appid", "b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22")
        .build();`
- Have a look at this URI `content://com.example.app/ExampleTable/2` for content provider.
- Since it contains a numerical number at the end, pointing to a single table item, therefore to create such URI we have to use **withAppendedId (Uri contentUri, long id)** method after appending the path segment using **appendPath (String newSegment)** method

  `Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.example.app").buildUpon()
                    .appendPath("ExampleTable")
                    .build()`

  `Uri newUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, 2);`

**Do notice**-

- All the methods defined in Uri.Builder class are useful for building an Uri object.
- All the methods defined in ContentUris class are useful for working with Uri objects that use the `content` scheme.

**Note**-

- Encoding of path segments should be done before appending it to Uri object specially if we are planning to build a URL from it using-
  `URL url = new URL(Uri_to_string);`
- To append Strings at the end of Uri object, which is called **path**, we have to use **appendPath (String newSegment)** method.

**Explore more**-

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html
  (Uri.Builder | Official documentation)
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html
  (ContentUris | Official documentation)
- [Why do you need to encode URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152738/why-do-you-need-to-encode-urls)
  (Why do you need to encode URLs? | StackOverFlow)