# Passing variable via query string truncates plus symbol

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am wondering how to pass a variable in Javascript as `+4` and then retrieve it as `+4` in php.

No matter what I do, whenever I store a `+4"`, and verify its being stored as such, when I retrieve it the `+` is gone and all I get is the number (i.e. `4`).

Here's what I've got:

**file.js**

```
var testString = "+4";
console.log(testString);
window.location.href = "file.php?testString=" + testString;
```

OUTPUT: `+4`

**file.php**

```
$testString = $_GET["testString"];
echo $testString;
```

OUTPUT: `4`

I know I can always append the "+", but that just seems like an extra process that shouldn't be necessary; I'd rather pass the variable properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) your parameters:

```
var testString = "+4";
console.log(testString);
window.location.href = "file.php?testString=" + encodeURIComponent(testString);
```

There's a few questions/resources that can help you understand why this is required:

- [Why do you need to encode URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152738/why-do-you-need-to-encode-urls)
- [Encoding URL's via lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/encoding-urls-3467463)
- [Introduction to URL encoding](https://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/)
- [The developer documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)